# Awful nested timers, how do I refactor?

Tags: c#, timer, delegates, refactoring

I've a method consisting of an ugly 13 parameters, but I can't figure out how to turn these into proper submethods and still function exactly the same, stopping after three iterations, using the correct parameters, closing off with a different method, etc. Would someone help me in the right direction?

```
//Three part animation
    public void SetPlayerAnimation(int location, int x1, int y1, TimeSpan duration1, string sprite1, int x2, int y2, TimeSpan duration2, string sprite2, int x3, int y3, TimeSpan duration3, string sprite3, string endsprite)
    {
        //Get the sprite object to be animated
        TranslateTarget = "Sprite" + location.ToString();
        OnPropertyChanged("TranslateTarget");

        //Start first part
        RunAnimation(location, x1, y1, duration1, sprite1);

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = duration1;
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += (s, args) =>
            {
                //Start second part
                RunAnimation(location, x2, y2, duration2, sprite2);

                timer.Stop();

                var timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
                timer2.Interval = duration2;
                timer2.Start();
                timer2.Tick += (s2, args2) =>
                   {
                       //Start third part
                       RunAnimation(location, x3, y3, duration3, sprite3);
                       timer2.Stop();

                       var timer3 = new DispatcherTimer();
                       timer3.Interval = duration2;
                       timer3.Start();
                       timer3.Tick += (s3, args3) =>
                           {
                               //End with a final sprite
                               SetPlayerSprite(location, endsprite);
                               timer3.Stop();
                           };
                   };
            };
    }
```

Comment: Run a single timer, or perhaps even a proper game loop. Each time the timer ticks, or the game loop pulses, check the time and if anything is due to be updated, update it.

Comment: Hmn, the program I'm writing is pretty procedural though. Once every 20 seconds or so there's a command, and once the animation is triggered, it should simply 'run', it always finishes, and never changes its behavior after it started. Wouldn't a full game loop be a bit overkill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use async/await and all your troubles go away!

```
public void SetPlayerAnimation(int location, int x1, int y1, TimeSpan duration1, string sprite1, int x2, int y2, TimeSpan duration2, string sprite2, int x3, int y3, TimeSpan duration3, string sprite3, string endsprite)
{
    //Get the sprite object to be animated
    TranslateTarget = "Sprite" + location.ToString();
    OnPropertyChanged("TranslateTarget");
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        async () => {
            RunAnimation(location, x1, y1, duration1, sprite1);
            await Task.Delay(duration1);
            RunAnimation(location, x2, y2, duration2, sprite2);
            await Task.Delay(duration2);
            RunAnimation(location, x3, y3, duration3, sprite3);
            await Task.Delay(duration2);
            SetPlayerSprite(location, endsprite);

        }, // this will use current synchronization context
        CancellationToken.None, 
        TaskCreationOptions.None, 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

}
```

Comment: So.. beautiful. I'm getting an error, "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependecyObject". Is this a new SO question, or can it be answered here?

Comment: Ok, you need to capture the ui synchronization context, so you should use Task.Factory.StartNew instaed of Task.Run. See edit. Untested.

Comment: Sepnder, there's no point for `StartNew` here (or `Run`, for that matter).  You may as well just inline those operations and make the whole method `async`.  It would be different if you had access to the `SyncrhonizationContext` representing the UI thread, but as it is, either you're in the UI thread and `StartNew` is pointless, or you're not in the UI thread and `StartNew` is *still* pointless.

Comment: I missed the code itself had been updated. StartNew and TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSyncContext make the code work perfectly fine!

Comment: @Servy, I didn't want to get into the issue of making the entire callstack async, so using StartNew means I can do it without this concern. Of course, if OP is confident, they might choose to mark the entire method as async and potentially work their way up the callstack. I just wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @spender Doing that is functionally equivalent to just making the method `async void`, at least for all practical purposes the method is async, you just prohibit the caller from being able to observe when it completes, or what its result is.  It's not like the method is actually synchronous or anything.  You lose nothing making the method `async`, and you only ever gain by making it `async Task` in that the caller at least has the *option* of observing when it completes.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a direction... A step in the right direction is:

- Replace all anonymous methods with real methods (with less code than the curent method)
- Make less parameters by put all parameters that ends with a number in one class

Comment: Making a class from the sets of parameters makes sense, I'll do that right now. I'm not sure how to replace all the anon methods with real methods though, there's subtle differences in each iteration that makes it pretty tough.

Comment: The code after "(s, args) =>", "(s2, args2)" and "(s3, args3) is now an anonymous method but you could replace it with 3 different real methods.

Comment: Aha, I see! Yes, that;s more logical than I expected. Just cause the code isn't reusable doesn't mean it won't be better maintainable if I split it. Now to figure out how to pass multiple parameters to a timer.Tick function, but I'm sure I can figure that out.

Comment: Using named methods, over anonymous methods, would make this code quite a lot messier, as he would lose the ability to close over the relevant information.  The effort that would be required in getting that information to the named methods would almost certainly be worse than what's there.

Comment: @Servy Al lot of anonymous methods makes the method to long, making it harder to read. I prefer a single responsebily because the names of the separate methods tell you what the methods do, there are no parameters that has nothing to do with the responsibility and also it is easier to unit test.

Comment: If none of the methods closed over any variables, I'd agree with you, but they do, so the refactor that it would take to make the data accessible in all of the relevant methods is...involved.  The fact that you didn't bother to post the code should be some indication.  If it's really a trivial refactor, you should be able to include it.  Spender's solution, on the other hand, (or at least the general approach of using `await Task.Delay`, *dramatically* improves readability, design, and is much easier to write than either solution, by a mile.