# How do I make this method use timers and params?

Tags: c#, timer, parameters

Using the same code as [Awful nested timers, how do I refactor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287472/awful-nested-timers-how-do-i-refactor/22287602#22287602), though the question is substantially different enough for me to ask a new one.

Basically, I have an array of 'Movement' classes, and I want to 'Run' them all after eachother; when they're all done, I want to finally set the image to something specific.

I was thinking of using a foreach loop and then putting a timer on the end of the foreach before it can continue? I can't get it to work though. Could someone help me, how do I get this method to be usable with as long a list of 'movements' as I want?

What I want is to have a method

```
public void SetPlayerAnimation(int location, string endsprite, params Movement[] parts)
{
    //Get the sprite object to be animated
    TranslateTarget = "Sprite" + location.ToString();
    OnPropertyChanged("TranslateTarget");

    ...stuff here that can have as many 'Movement parts' as are passed along.
    ...and waits with the next iteration until the previous one is done.
    ...but doesn't spin around in this method, so preferably using events, maybe?

    //End with a final sprite
    SetPlayerSprite(location, endsprite);
}
```

What I have is the code below.

```
//Three part animation
public void SetPlayerAnimation(int location, string endsprite, Movement part1, Movement part2, Movement part3)
{
    //Get the sprite object to be animated
    TranslateTarget = "Sprite" + location.ToString();
    OnPropertyChanged("TranslateTarget");

    //Start first part
    part1.Run(location);

    //Wait till its done to start the second part.
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = part1.duration;
    timer.Start();
    timer.Tick += (s, args) =>
        {
            //Start second part
            part2.Run(location);

            timer.Stop();

            //Wait till its done to start the third part.
            var timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer2.Interval = part2.duration;
            timer2.Start();
            timer2.Tick += (s2, args2) =>
               {
                   //Start third part
                   part3.Run(location);
                   timer2.Stop();

                   //When we're through all parts, wait till its done and set the endsprite.
                   var timer3 = new DispatcherTimer();
                   timer3.Interval = part3.duration;
                   timer3.Start();
                   timer3.Tick += (s3, args3) =>
                       {
                           //End with a final sprite
                           SetPlayerSprite(location, endsprite);
                           timer3.Stop();
                       };
               };
        };
}
```

Comment: I took a punt at your other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287472/awful-nested-timers-how-do-i-refactor/22333015#22333015 ). You may want to take a look and reconsider this question.

Comment: Seems like you need an engine that stores the movements in a queue, then as they finish grabs the next one and starts it. I could provide an example if that solution sounds good to you.

Comment: i think `start()` will reset the interval, try calling start last after you have set up the timer object.

Comment: It sounds good to me. Spenders solution would've been ideal, but it seems to error due to some threading stuff, probably WPF related. Would you please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try something like this:

```
private void RepetitionRoutine(Movement part, Action next, int location)
{
    part.Run(location);

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = part.duration;
    timer.Start();
    timer.Tick += (s, args) =>
        {
            next();
            timer.Stop();
        }
}

public class MovementChain
{
    Action _next;
    Movement _part;
    int _location;
    public MovementChain(Movement part, int location)
    {
        _part = part;
        _location = location;
    }

    public void setNext(Action next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        RepetitionRoutine(_part, _next, _location);
    }
}

public void SetPlayerAnimation(int location, string endsprite, params Movement[] parts)
{
    //Get the sprite object to be animated
    if(parts.Count() == 0)
        return;
    TranslateTarget = "Sprite" + location.ToString();
    OnPropertyChanged("TranslateTarget");   

    MovementChain first;
    MovementChain last;
    foreach(Movement part in parts)
    {
        MovementChain current = new MovementChain(part, location);
        if(first == null)
        {
            first = current;
            last = first;
        } 
        else
        {
            last.setNext(current.execute);
            last = current;
        }       
    }
    last.setNext(()=>SetPlayerSprite(location, endsprite));
    first.execute();
}
```

Comment: At this point your method `RepetitionRoutine` is, more or less, just a re-implementation of `Task.Delay`, but with some features missing.

Comment: Yes, just refactored original code as asked to work with Movement list, keeping behavior closest as possible from original code